# How Can I Filter Rows In Two Columns

Tags: sqlite

I have this query in sqlite that gives me 2 columns

- 1,8
- 14,4
- 4,14
- 5,11

I wanna filter one of these kind of rows 14,4 or 4,14 
what should i do

```
select p1.id,p2.id from GrpPoints p1 inner join GrpPoints p2 on P1.id <> p2.id and P1.GisBuildingId = P2.GisBuildingId And
 Distance(P1.InsecPoint,P2.InsecPoint) < 0.0001
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi there, please look at this [guide how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). At the Moment your question formating is not ideal and it unclear what your exact input and what your expected output is.

Answer (score 0):

Your join condition matches both combinations of points. Change it so that one combination is filtered out.

In this case, you can choose that combination where the IDs are in ascending order.
Replace:

```
on P1.id <> p2.id
```

with:

```
on P1.id <  p2.id
```